# How to read the last line in CSV line in GATLING

Tags: scala, csv, gatling, scala-gatling

I use feeders from a csv file, and i want to read always the last line in this file:

```
val actors= csv("./src/test/resources/Data/ksp-acteurs.csv").circular


      .feed(actors)
  .exec(http("K_actors")
    .get("https://URL/ksp-acteurs/${Col1}")    //need to extract the last value in this column    
    .header("Authorization","Bearer ${jwtoken}")
    .check(status is 200))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like this:

```
val feeder = csv("./src/test/resources/Data/ksp-acteurs.csv")
val lastLine = feeder.readRecords.last.values
```

but the important thing is that you call `readRecords` before you call `circular`, because in this case `readRecord` will not be able to find last line and test will fail with out-of-memory exception.

Comment: Note: csv("./src/test/resources/Data/ksp-acteurs.csv") is wrong. It should be csv("Data/ksp-acteurs.csv")